# Consuming partially embedded data with Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

A service I am calling (which I have no control over) returns the following JSON payload:

```
{
   name: 'name',
   tags: [
       {
           name: 'name',
           users: [ 2, 3, 4 ]
       },
       // ........
   ]
}
```

I have written a custom serializer to handle the embedded data:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(
    DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
        attrs: {
            tags: { embedded: 'always' },
        }
    }
);
```

Now the users within Tags is not embeded. How do I tell Ember that it needs to go fetch the entities based on the user IDs within the tags object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Model, do you have defined the user property defined as `async`?

```
// Ember.Model
user: DS.hasMany('user', { async: true })
```

Comment: Is this the model for the containing post, or the model for the tag?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's for the Tag

Comment: Shouldn't it be DS.hasMany? Also, yes Tag has users: `DS.hasMany('user', { async: true })`

Comment: I just found that my handlebars template was missing the e in users. I'll mark you as answer though, thanks for your help.

Comment: oh, you're right with hasMany, my bad, thanks... so didn't you have to put `{async: true}` after all?